# Is there a Google Apps Script that will move the data from a CSV attachment of a GMail email to a defined Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Solution: https://riptutorial.com/google-apps-script/example/20730/get-csv-file-attached-to-a-mail

Google Apps Script Novice trying to set up a script that will run on a time-bound trigger to find the most recent email (will be auto-labeled based on unique sender email) and then auto-transfer the single CSV file's single tab of data to a defined Google Sheet.

Here's a list of how-tos and walkthroughs I've tried:

https://ctrlq.org/code/20279-import-csv-into-google-spreadsheet
[Google Apps Script - GMail to Google Sheets - Get Oldest Unread Email in Thread's .csv Attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49861771/google-apps-script-gmail-to-google-sheets-get-oldest-unread-email-in-thread)
[Retrieve csv attachment file from gmail and place the data in a google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688560/retrieve-csv-attachment-file-from-gmail-and-place-the-data-in-a-google-spreadshe)
[How do I convert jpg or png to blob on google app script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994351/how-do-i-convert-jpg-or-png-to-blob-on-google-app-script)

I've watched videos that run through the basics of using Google Apps Scripts on Youtube, signed up for and have completed the first 1/3 of the "Complete Java Certification Course" by Imtiaz Ahmad on Udemy, read through various documentation re Classes and Methods used in Google Apps Scripts and still cannot get this to work. I receive an "TypeError: cannot read property 'length' of undefined...", and it appears my problem stems from the attachment being "undefined".

```
function test(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data =  ss.getRange(1, 1,6,2).getValues();

  var threads = GmailApp.search("from:XXXXSENDERSEMAIL@GMAIL.COM");
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl();
  Logger.log(ss1);

  Logger.log(threads);
  Logger.log(message);  
  Logger.log(attachment);

  Logger.log(data);


  var newarray =  attachment[0];

  ss.getRange(1, 5, newarray.length, newarray[0].length).setValues(newarray);
}
```

Expected results: finds the csv attachment, gets data from the csv attachment, writes data on a "Master" spreadsheet that is updated daily (clearvalues/setvalues).

Error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMessages' of undefined (line 30, file "Code")

Comment: Perhaps [this may help](https://riptutorial.com/google-apps-script/example/20730/get-csv-file-attached-to-a-mail)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve csv attachment file from gmail and place the data in a google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688560/retrieve-csv-attachment-file-from-gmail-and-place-the-data-in-a-google-spreadshe)

Comment: I cannot see a line 30 nor  'getMessages' in your code snippet, but as for   "TypeError: cannot read property 'length' of undefined...": Think about it - `newarray.length` would retrieve the length of an array called `newarray`, but in your case, you assign to the variable `newarray` a single attachment (element with index 0 of the array `attachement[]`). Thus, newarray is not an array and consequently does not have any length - this is what throws you the error. Btw, attachment does not look like an array neither, so probably there is no element  `attachment[0]`.